# buildr: package dependencies into a single jar

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, packaging, buildr

I have a java project that is built with [buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/) and that has some external dependencies:

```
repositories.remote << "http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2"
repositories.remote << "http://packages.example/"

define "myproject" do
  compile.options.target = '1.5'
  project.version = "1.0.0"
  compile.with 'dependency:dependency-xy:jar:1.2.3'
  compile.with 'dependency2:dependency2:jar:4.5.6'

  package(:jar)
end
```

I want this to build a single standalone jar file that includes all these dependencies.

How do I do that?

(there's a logical followup question: [How can I strip all the unused code from the included dependencies and only package the classes I actually use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284769/package-java-applet-with-minimal-dependencies-autojar-plugin-for-buildr)?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I'm doing right now.  This uses autojar to pull only the necessary dependencies:

```
def add_dependencies(pkg)
  tempfile = pkg.to_s.sub(/.jar$/, "-without-dependencies.jar")
  mv pkg.to_s, tempfile

  dependencies = compile.dependencies.map { |d| "-c #{d}"}.join(" ")
  sh "java -jar tools/autojar.jar -baev -o #{pkg} #{dependencies} #{tempfile}"
end
```

and later:

```
package(:jar)
package(:jar).enhance { |pkg| pkg.enhance { |pkg| add_dependencies(pkg) }}
```

*(caveat: I know little about buildr, this could be totally the wrong approach.  It works for me, though)*

Comment: This is the actual right answer. My answer below just adds the jars to the `lib` folder which works in Hadoop but nowhere else.

Comment: This works fine - forking out to the shell is ok to get the job done. Maybe a fancier way would be this kind of approach https://gist.github.com/981589

Answer (score 7):

I'm also learning Buildr and currently I'm packing Scala runtime with my application this way:

```
package(:jar).with(:manifest => _('src/MANIFEST.MF')).exclude('.scala-deps')
  .merge('/var/local/scala/lib/scala-library.jar')
```

No idea if this is inferior to autojar (comments are welcome), but seems to work with a simple example. Takes 4.5 minutes to package that scala-library.jar thought.

Comment: the nice thing about autojar is that it also strips dependencies that are never used in your program (based on bytecode inspection) - so in theory you should get a smaller result file

Comment: THIS is the right answer since it uses a build in buildr function

Comment: I'll second this; this is the way to do it using buildr.

Comment: For those needing help with Ruby, put the two together for an easy answer: `package(:jar).merge(compile.dependencies)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) for my example:

```
cascading_dev_jars = Dir[_("#{ENV["CASCADING_HOME"]}/build/cascading-{core,xml}-*.jar")]
#...
package(:jar).include cascading_dev_jars, :path => "lib"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I create an Uberjar with Buildr, this customization of what is put into the Jar and how the Manifest is created:

```
assembly_dir = 'target/assembly'
main_class = 'com.something.something.Blah'

artifacts = compile.dependencies

artifacts.each do |artifact|
    Unzip.new( _(assembly_dir) => artifact ).extract
end

# remove dirs from assembly that should not be in uberjar
FileUtils.rm_rf( "#{_(assembly_dir)}/example/package" )
FileUtils.rm_rf( "#{_(assembly_dir)}/example/dir" )

# create manifest file
File.open( _("#{assembly_dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"), 'w') do |f| 
    f.write("Implementation-Title: Uberjar Example\n")
    f.write("Implementation-Version: #{project_version}\n") 
    f.write("Main-Class: #{main_class}\n")
    f.write("Created-By: Buildr\n")                 
end

present_dir = Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir _(assembly_dir)
puts "Creating #{_("target/#{project.name}-#{project.version}.jar")}" 
`jar -cfm #{_("target/#{project.name}-#{project.version}.jar")} #{_(assembly_dir)}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .`
Dir.chdir present_dir
```

There is also a version that [supports Spring](https://gist.github.com/1250815), by concatenating all the *spring.schemas*